# Getting 'KeyError' while reading '.ini' file

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a python project in PyCharm, i have a following directory structure:

```
MyProject
 |_d1
   |_d2
     |_d3
      |_Main.py
      |_config.ini
```

config.ini

```
; config.ini
[DEFAULT]
SECRET_KEY = secret-key-of-myapp
```

main.py:

```
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    print('==>', config.sections())
    secret_key = config['DEFAULT']['SECRET_KEY']
    print(secret_key)
```

I am getting this error

```
  raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

Comment: What does `print(config)` give you?

Comment: I think it is not able to recognize config.ini. Can you hardcode your config.ini path```config.read('full_path_to_config.ini')``` aand check whether that works fine?

Comment: `config.sections()` gives `[]`

Answer (score 0):

when I run the program , it gives me the following. I use python 3.7 for testing.
reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
print('==>', config.__dict__)
secret_key = config['DEFAULT']['SECRET_KEY']
print(secret_key)



> ==> {'_dict': <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, '_sections': OrderedDict(), '_defaults': OrderedDict([('secret_key',
> 'secret-key-of-myapp')]), '_converters':
> <configparser.ConverterMapping object at 0x00000000020645C0>,
> '_proxies': OrderedDict([('DEFAULT', <Section: DEFAULT>)]),
> '_delimiters': ('=', ':'), '_optcre': re.compile('\n       
> (?P<option>.*?)                    # very permissive!\n       
> \\s*(?P<vi>=|:)\\s*              # any number of space/tab,\n         
> # followed by any of t, re.VERBOSE), '_comment_prefixes': ('#', ';'), '_inline_comment_prefixes': (), '_strict': True, '_allow_no_value':
> False, '_empty_lines_in_values': True, 'default_section': 'DEFAULT',
> '_interpolation': <configparser.BasicInterpolation object at
> 0x0000000002B9FA90>} secret-key-of-myapp
```

Comment: did you find out the reason?